# Stress testing a webpage

Tags: php, testing, web

I have a web based phone dialer, which I need to stress test. It requires human action to terminate a call and dial next call. I need to simulate a situation under which 100 users will use the service concurrently. I am not allowed to modify the javascript which dials the next number. Also, there exist a login page, after which the users can reach the dial pad.

Any idea how do I do this?

Comment: Hard to say without any more details on what the system does and how it does it. Hire 100 humans? :o)

Comment: goto facebook and offer free credit to make a phonecall and you can test millions....mayb

Comment: Its all about sending HTTP request. JMeter can do this very well.

Comment: @Shiplu - What about sessions for each user :)

Comment: Sessions are created by sending HTTP requests. please check the manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) to stress test your web app. First setup [JMeter as proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) to record the http transactions. then using those transactions as template set it up to send 100 concurrent request.

Comment: That's a very good suggestion! Few other testing tools that I found on the internet, such as HP Load Runner do the same thing. But since I am on RHEL, your suggestion work the best for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **[xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/)** could be a good beginning to resolve your human interaction simulation. But how to solve the 100 users concurrently, I don't know yet. Hopes this helps.

Comment: I need to have 100 desktops for your solutions to work. A bit off from my budget :) But thanks for the pointer...